# Morris chart with date issue

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I use morris.js library for charts.

Now I need to show date and price at one chart so I write:

```
Morris.Area({
    element: 'line-example',
    data: [
        {
            period: 2016-11-22 16:36:16,
            price: 22        
        },
        {
            period: 2016-11-06 16:36:16,
            price: 61         
        },
        {
            period: 2016-10-31 16:36:16,
            price: 49
        },
        {
            period: 2016-11-08 11:16:53,
            price: 131
        },
        {
            period: 2016-11-10 13:52:10,
            price: 85        
        },
        {
            period: 2016-11-14 12:16:15,
            price: 72
        },
        {
            period: 2016-11-17 14:36:34,
            price: 206    
        },                  
    ],
    lineColors: ['#a5d9c7'],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['price'],
    labels: ['Day'],
    xLabels: 'day',
    pointSize: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    resize: true,
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridLineColor: '#e0e0e0',
    hideHover: 'auto'    
});
```

http://jsbin.com/sedusigamo/1/edit?html,js,output

Why my code won't work? What can be an issue here?
I read at documentation that date can be in format like in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> Timestamps are accepted in the form of `millisecond timestamps` (as returned by Date.getTime() or as `strings` in the following formats:

It say as `strings` or `timestamps`. Your dates are `strings`, not `timestamps`, so you need to add quotes `"` for your `period` data like this:

```
data: [
{
    period: "2016-11-22 16:36:16",
    price: 22
},
{
    period: "2016-11-06 16:36:16",
    price: 61
},
{
    period: "2016-10-31 16:36:16",
    price: 49
},
{
    period: "2016-11-08 11:16:53",
    price: 131
},
        {
    period: "2016-11-10 13:52:10",
    price: 85
},
{
    period: "2016-11-14 12:16:15",
    price: 72

},
{
    period: "2016-11-17 14:36:34",
    price: 206
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wabizokefi/1/edit?html,js,output